# Populate in dynamodb or Referencing in dynamoDb (Node.js/Javascript)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

How to **populate** or perform **referencing** in DynamoDb or there is any dynamo referencing functionality present? which could be used with javascript or node.js.

Comment: do you mean referencing another table ?

Comment: Just like Mongoose populate ... we can store ref to entity in other table

Answer (score 0):

There is no referencing functionality available on DynamoDB. Even the frameworks like [vogels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vogels) which is used for modeling and mapping doesn't have this feature.

In other words, there is no `lookup` feature (i.e. present on MongoDB) available on DynamoDB.

Comment: @notiionquest is there any way to achieve this in dynamodb?

Comment: You may need to develop your own code. However, you should have some valid use case why you wanted this feature? Sometimes, you can't have like-to-like functionality in every database. If you are from MongoDB background, please first think about the data model suitable with DynamoDB and your use case rather thinking in the perspective of MongoDB design.